# how to boot from a backup disk created by dd

Tags: dd

I use dd command to backup a disk.

```
# dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

but when I boot from the backup disk, I got a error message
check filesystem failed!

I do not know how to settle this problem.
I thought the sdb is a copy of sda, so it can be booted.
Then why it turns out this error message?

Comment: Maybe sdb is smaller? `blockdev --getsz /dev/sda /dev/sdb` Or volumes get mounted via /dev/disk/by-id/ which cannot work any more as the disk ID has changed.

Comment: I can sure that the two disk space are same. /dev/sdb is a new fresh disk. Does it matter with gvfs ?

Comment: What is the fstab entry for the volume with the failing fsck?

Comment: the same as sda, i do not edit the fstab in sdb

Comment: i boot the backup disk on another linux box, and then type fdisk -l i found this /dev/sdb1 ... Partion 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Comment: What is the output of `sfdisk --unit S -l /dev/sda /dev/sdb`?

Answer (score 0):

> Partion 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Sounds like something that could potentially be fixed by directly editing the partition table.
I'm know quite sure how to do than with Linux but should give you a good starting point.

Comment: yes, i found that 'dd' doesn't copy superblock. I fixed this problem by two steps. 1) #fdisk /dev/sdb  2) w

Comment: I don't know why dd don't copy superblock even i use #dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb, If dd is byte-copy, why does it ingore superblock?

Answer (score 0):

can you compare with fdisk or sfdisk the partition tables of the two disks.
In case of any mismatch :
try to restore the original partition table :
1) sfdisk -d /dev/sda >/root/partition.img
2) sfdisk /dev/sdb