# Experiences with using `dd` to copy multi-partition, multi-FS device

Tags: dd, disk-image

I have a disc with several partitions on, each of which has a different kind of file system (ext3, ext4, and, let's say, NTFS).  I want to know if I can copy the whole disc to a new one (which is of larger capacity) using `dd`, preferably in a single operation.

To forestall unnecessary effort, let me clarify a few things.  I'm not interested in other ways to do it (I know the right way, and third-party software is not desirable).  I'm not all that interested in theoretical answers ("it ought to work").  I'm extremely interested in anyone else's experiences trying to do such a thing.

I know the real right answer is "try it and see", but I'm 250 miles from the disc in question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have to do this, and you have to be in a *really bad place* to even *think* about doing this...

It's safest to copy the partitions individually. For instance:

```
# Install  a temporary ssh key so we don't have to deal with lots of
# password prompts, remember to remove it from authorized_keys later
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@host

# Copy everything, you can go have breakfast - and probably lunch -
# while you wait
for partition in /dev/sdb?*
do
    dd if=$partition | ssh user@host "dd of=$(basename $partition).img"
done
```

Wait a few minutes or hours for the copy to complete, and then begin your recovery from the disk images. For instance, on a new disk you may create a new partition table with partitions of the correct size to hold the disk images, and then `dd` the images back out to the new partitions.

---

Copying the *entire disk* (e.g. `dd if=/dev/sdb`) makes things more complicated, since you then have a full disk image you will probably have to split out into partitions somehow anyway. And if you're thinking of `dd`ing the entire drive directly to another physical disk, think again: sometimes you'll just lose when [the system refuses to acknowledge that the partition table and the new hard drive have anything to do with each other](https://serverfault.com/q/484341/126632).

If you *must* copy the entire disk in one shot (you likely don't have to, so don't think about this) then copy it to an *image file* and use [`kpartx`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/kpartx) to work with the partitions. For instance:

```
dd if=/dev/sdb | ssh user@host "dd of=sdb.img"
# Later, on the recovery host...
kpartx -l sdb.img
kpartx -a sdb.img
# Now you can...
mount -o ro /dev/mapper/loop0p1 /mnt/rescuep1
mount -o ro /dev/mapper/loop0p2 /mnt/rescuep2
# or copy to a new hard drive...
dd if=/dev/mapper/loop0p1 of=/dev/sdc1
dd if=/dev/mapper/loop0p2 of=/dev/sdc2
```

---

If the physical disk is having physical trouble, consider using `dd_rescue` instead (though you didn't really ask about that).